# How do I split multiple characters without using any imported libraries?

Tags: python, split

The string is:

```
line = 'a but tuba!'
```

I want to remove the spaces and the exclamation point so that when I use the `.split()` function, it will output as follows:

```
line = ['a','but','tuba']
```

I want to do this without using any imported libraries, just basic code.

Comment: is it only an exclamation point or possibly other characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove `!` by using [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) and then split the string using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split).

```
line = 'a but tuba!'
line = line.replace('!', '').split(' ')
print line
```

Output:

```
['a', 'but', 'tuba']
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest (and probably the only) way would be to strip the exclamation point and then split at a space:

```
line = 'a but tuba!'.strip('!').split(" ")
print line
>>>['a', 'but', 'tuba']
```